# How to implement DKIM for Domino mail server?

Tags: dkim, ibm-domino, opendkim

I'd like to write a Domino servlet that will stamp outgoing mail with a DKIM domain keys signature.  We would generate the Domino mail server DKIM signature and put it in a TXT file with the DNS manager.  How can I stamp an outgoing message with the encryption key?  We would then add the DKIM signature to the header prior to releasing from mail.box.

Answer (score 2):

Although [requested by many](https://domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com/ideas/IDEAMLCT-I-6), HTC Domino doesn't yet support DKIM nor DMARC. Implementing DKIM on Domino might not be as easy as writing a little servlet, as it involves [canonicalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.4), [computing hashes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.7) and [signing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.3) them. After that, you'd have to add a [signature header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.5) that has a strict format.

Although it's all documented in the [RFC 6376](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376), many things can go wrong. Therefore, I wouldn't recommend trying to write an own implementation for DKIM signing. On the other hand, if you did that and got it working, there's indeed a huge demand for this feature! Frankly, because you are asking this question on such an abstract level, you aren't quite there yet.

A more suitable solution might be **setting up another SMTP server in front of the Domino** server and configuring it to trust & DKIM stamp mail from Domino. There are e.g. many tutorials on how to achieve this with Postfix & OpenDKIM.

Comment: I would think I could implement openDKIM somehow so as not reinvent the wheel.  I have written lots of Java mail and mime handling scripts.  Canonicalization, computing hashes and singing are not difficult, just tedious.  I don't want to put an SMTP server in front of the Domino server.  I want a Domino solution, if I have to write it myself. ;-)